# How to run "composer update" on test/production server?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.1, updates

I'm developing an application in laravel, I have completed it on localhost, but when I run it on test server it shows me error

```
Class 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found
```

I think it need to update composer. But how do I do it on test server..!

Please help me I'm new to laravel and web hosting.
Thank you.

Comment: if you need to run composer update you need to access  your hosting server through ssh, you can use putty on windows on linux or mac you can use terminal, first you need to enable ssh on your hosting server, if you have dedicated hosting or vps you can install composer other wise you have to upload composer.phar through ftp.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do a

```
composer install
```

Comment: what is your hosting server?

Comment: " Dreamhost" is the hosting server.

Comment: @aldrin27 actualy it does provide an answer but i didnt expect that he doesnt know how to access the server through ssh :)

Comment: @Aamir  [This is how to connect to SSH in dream host](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216041267-SSH-overview)

Answer (score 0):

you have 3 options

1. Copy `/vendor` folder via **FTP** - simple
2. Install and run Composer via **terminal** - can be forbidden
3. Run composer update **from PHP**

This is complete solution for **3.** with description.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38396047/2583652

code here: https://github.com/whipsterCZ/laravel-libraries/blob/master/public/composer.php