# How to run composer update on PHP server?

Tags: php, composer-php, server-side, phar

Is there a way to run `composer update` command on our production/test environment?

Problem is that i don't have access for Command Line.

Comment: You can't use a terminal?

Comment: No i can't. This is the reason why a ask

Comment: [you shouldn't run `composer update`, but `composer install` on your lockfile](https://daylerees.com/the-composer-lock-file/) - obviously you cannot do that either, but it needs mentioning.

Comment: While generally discouraged, [you can version your vendor folder](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md), then you don't need access on the production server. However, the much better choice would be to just get a server with ssh access. They are *not that* expensive.

Comment: yes i could version /vendor, but I have the reasons not to do that. i.e. Some libraries has its own .gitignore with its dependecies and these are not included in GIT repo  :(  every commit than brakes app..

Comment: but you have big point that i should rather run `composer install`

Answer (score 5):

Yes. there is a solution. but it could demands some server configuration...
and some of these are forbidden by default due to security risks!!

download `composer.phar` https://getcomposer.org/download/ 
 - this is PHP Archive which can be extracted via `Phar()` and executed as regular library.

create new php file and place it to web public folder. i.e. `/public/composer.php`

or download at https://github.com/whipsterCZ/laravel-libraries/blob/master/public/composer.php

---

Configuration

```
<?php

//TODO! Some Authorization - Whitelisted IP, Security tokens...


echo '<pre>
   ______
  / ____/___  ____ ___  ____  ____  ________  _____
 / /   / __ \/ __ `__ \/ __ \/ __ \/ ___/ _ \/ ___/
/ /___/ /_/ / / / / / / /_/ / /_/ (__  )  __/ /
\____/\____/_/ /_/ /_/ .___/\____/____/\___/_/  UPDATE
                    /_/

';
define('ROOT_DIR',realpath('../'));
define('EXTRACT_DIRECTORY', ROOT_DIR. '/composer');
define('HOME_DIRECTORY', ROOT_DIR. '/composer/home');
define('COMPOSER_INITED', file_exists(ROOT_DIR.'/vendor'));

set_time_limit(100);
ini_set('memory_limit',-1);

if (!getenv('HOME') && !getenv('COMPOSER_HOME')) {
    putenv("COMPOSER_HOME=".HOME_DIRECTORY);
}
```

Extracting composer library

```
if (file_exists(EXTRACT_DIRECTORY.'/vendor/autoload.php') == true) {
    echo "Extracted autoload already exists. Skipping phar extraction as presumably it's already extracted.\n";
}
else{
    $composerPhar = new Phar("../composer.phar");
    //php.ini set phar.readonly=0
    $composerPhar->extractTo(EXTRACT_DIRECTORY);
}
```

running Composer Command

```
// change directory to root
chdir(ROOT_DIR);

//This requires the phar to have been extracted successfully.
require_once (EXTRACT_DIRECTORY.'/vendor/autoload.php');

//Use the Composer classes
use Composer\Console\Application;
use Composer\Command\UpdateCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;


//Create the commands
$args = array('command' => 'update');
if(!COMPOSER_INITED) { 
    echo "This is first composer run: --no-scripts option is applies\n";
    $args['--no-scripts']=true; }        
}
$input = new ArrayInput($args);

//Create the application and run it with the commands
$application = new Application();
$application->setAutoExit(false);
$application->setCatchExceptions(false);
try {
    //Running commdand php.ini allow_url_fopen=1 && proc_open() function available
    $application->run($input);
    echo 'Success';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage()."\n";
}
```

But **Better will be performing** `composer install`, according to composer.lock which is last dependency configuration tested from local environment

only change is

`$args = array('command' => 'install');`

Comment: is it ok like this?

Comment: It's a lot better :)

Answer (score 2):

The best idea is to NOT run Composer commands on the production server, but outside of it. Have a deployment script - your code has to be put on the server anyway, and it shouldn't matter if you add the dependencies ON the server after you uploaded the code, or before the upload.

The workflow would be like this: Have a local machine, checkout your code from the repo, run `composer install`, and then upload everything to the server. That sounds like a four line script to me:

```
git archive master | tar -x -C /deploy/application
pushd /deploy/application && composer install
popd
scp /deploy/application user@remoteserver:/srv/www/htdocs
```

Yes, you'd need some error handling in case something goes wrong, to stop the script from deploying a nonworking site. Also, optimizing uploads by using `rsync` would be a suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this also:
1) Download the latest composer.phar 
2) Execute a command from PHP script to do the wor using downloaded composer file

This is a temporary solution but can work for the immediate need.

Comment: It may really be a bad idea, but please explain why. Don't just vote down.